# Need help understanding how this Haskell code works

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to learn Haskell programming language by trying to figure out some pieces of code.

I have these 2 small functions but I have no idea how to test them on ghci.
What parameters should I use when calling these functions?

```
total :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
total function count = foldr(\x count -> function x + count) 0 [0..count]
```

The function above is supposed to for the given value `n`, return `f 0 + f 1 +  ... + f n`.

However when calling the function I don't understand what to put in the `f` part. `n` is just an integer, but what is `f` supposed to be?

---

```
iter :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
iter n f
  | n > 0 = f . iter (n-1) f
  | otherwise = id

iter' :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
iter' n = foldr (.) id . replicate n
```

This function is supposed to compose the given function `f :: a -> a` with itself `n :: Integer` times, e.g., `iter 2 f = f . f`.

Once again when calling the function I don't understand what to put instead of `f` as a parameter.

Comment: In the first example, `f` is supposed to be a function that takes an integer and returns an integer. In the second example, `f` is supposed to be a function that takes an argument of any type and returns a value of the same type.

Comment: in `total` the use of `count` as both the input integer and the accumulator of `foldr` is weird. Is that intended?

Comment: Did you write `total`? There's a much simpler way to implement it. (Use `map` and `sum`.)

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, you use any value for `f` such that

```
f 0 + f 1 +  ... + f n
```

indeed makes sense. You could use any numeric function capable of accepting an `Integer` argument and returning an `Integer` value, like `(1 +)`, `abs`, `signum`, `error "error"`, `(\x -> x^3-x^2+5*x-2)`, etc.

"Makes sense" here means that the resulting expression has type ("typechecks", in a vernacular), not that it would run without causing an error.

To your second question, any function that returns the same type of value as its argument, like `(1+)`, `(2/)` etc.

Comment: When I try to do the function for example (1+) I get an error     * Couldn't match expected type `Integer'
                  with actual type `a0 -> a0'
    * In the second argument of `total', namely `(1 +)'
      In the expression: total 3 (1 +)
      In an equation for `it': it = total 3 (1 +)

Comment: as you've probably figured out yourself by now (judging by you deleting the question -- you really shouldn't do that!) the proper call is `total (1 +) 3`. The first argument is the function, and the second is the number, as indicated by `total`'s type, `(Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer`. (also, when posting code snippets which contain backticks, surround the snippets with _double_ backticks, and it'll work).